# selecting a particular index from array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs

i am doing an axios call and the data i receive is array of objects from the backend inside each of which contains a value called result(format - result:"Hello"). There is a button which when clicked should go to the particular index and fetch the value of result specified and pass it . Not sure how exactly to accomplish this .

```
componentDidMount(){
let payload = this.props.location.state
axios.post(`http://localhost:8200/service/${this.service_name}/requests`,payload)
  .then( response=>{
    console.log(response.data.methods)
    this.setState({
      methods:response.data.methods,
      trace:response.data.methods[0].result  
      // Here above i have written ,but it only fetches from index[0] statically , 
        i want it to select the result of the particular button i press. 
    });
  })
 }
 playitHandler(){
  let payload = {
  "service_name":this.service_name,
  "trace_id":this.state.trace
  }
 }
 <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.playitHandler()}>Display</button>
```

Tried passing index to ComponentDidMount(){} , i guess we cant pass it there , since it threw an error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the fetch must be accomplished, exactly? Because, if you perform it when the page is loaded, then you can't retrieve specific data when you press a button.
As far as I can see it, you have two possibilities:

1. Make a `retrieveIndexData()` function, which takes in input the click event on a button. Inside this function you run the axios call and then you save the data in the index using `parseInt(ev.target.value)`. Though, I don't think this would be the best practice;
2. You add a property `selectedIndex` in the state, and, when you click an a button, you save the relative index in that property. Instead, in the axios call you save ALL the indexes. Then, you can work on the data you have selected clicking on a button using `this.state.trace[this.state.selectedIndex]`;

**EDIT:** Let me explain better the second point. In the state you have the property `response.data.methods` in which you save all the elements of the `methods` array, including the one you want to save in the `trace` property of the state.

Now, since you would just create redundancy in the state, in that `setState` I would write only: `this.setState({ methods: response.data.methods })`. You have all you need now in the state!

Finally, I supposed that the `button` element you show it's just a "0 Button", that if you press, you want the first method. So I guessed you also have a second Button that you consider the second element and so on. If that's correct, than I should expect something like this:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.playitHandler(0)}Display 0</button>
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.playitHandler(1)}Display 1</button>
...
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.playitHandler(100)}Display 100</button>
```

Supposed I'm right, then in `playitHandler()` you can just browse `this.state.methods` to retrieve what you want:

```
playitHandler(methodIndex) {
    let payload = {
        "service_name": this.service_name,
        "trace_id": this.state.methods[methodIndex]
    }
}
```

Is it more clear? I avoided the use of a `selectedIndex` property in the state in this example, though, I think this way is even more simpler.

Comment: sorry , didnt understand how exactly to save all indexes in selectedIndex . did you mean like this -   selectedIndex:response.data.methods[i] ?

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain better! Let me edit the comment here above.